# Saving JSON object in CouchDB from JavaScript

Tags: couchdb

I am retrieving a form value in JavaScript and converting it to a JSON object using `JSON.stringify()`.

Now I want to save it in CouchDB. Can anyone tell how to do that?

Comment: sorry its not fhtml its html.

Answer (score 2):

I think it was:

```
var json = {_id:1 friends:["friend1","friend2"]}
couchdb.save(json);
var friends = couchdb.open(1).friends;
```

Hope that could help you.

Comment: do we need to use any connector to get connected to couchDB database from our webpage?

Comment: Since you use  JavaScript there are two ways. First one is using a Wrapper (there must be a file called couch.js which comes with you installation of couchdb) and then you could use my code above. Second one is to use plain old HTTP and XMLHttpRequest, making request to your server instance using JSON. See [link](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Getting_started_with_JavaScript) for further information.