# How to write to CouchDB using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, couchdb

I have seen a [couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395338/how-do-you-post-data-to-couchdb-both-with-and-without-using-javascript) of [such](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570062/saving-json-object-in-couchdb-from-javascript) questions and read tutorials I could [find](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Getting_started_with_JavaScript). Unfortunately they all suppose I have some knowledge of something that I actually don't have and I don't even know the keywords of what I don't know.

I have a HTML page with some javascript in it. I can put the information in a string or javascript object. Now, how do I get it to my DB? How do I point where my DB is and how can the javascript authorize to the db so it could write?

Most of the tutorials only show how CouchDB works with the curl thing and I haven't seen a tutorial to make website interact with the database. Isn't that what CouchDB is meant for?

Comment: Are you using node.js or a non JS backend?

Comment: @sarwar, a fresh installation of CouchDB is all the backend I currently have.

Comment: Since you're using just JS and html I'd lean towards jquery.couch.js. I asked about the backend because the python couchdb interface is quite simple and intuitive if you have a python based server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sending REST requests from JavaScript (with jQuery) is very similar to what you would do with curl:

```
function create() {
  var o = {"name":"Bond"};
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/myDB/",
   contentType: "application/json",
   data: JSON.stringify(o),
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(data) {
     alert(data.id + " created !");
   }
  });
}
```

But be careful: the request will be blocked for security reasons if it is not retrieved from the same service as CouchDB. So put your HTML page as an attachment of your design document.

You will learn later how to use such scripts in "shows" or "lists". But let's begin with something simple.

Answer (score 5):

Just because I had so much trouble finding a clear answer on this too, here's how to do it in vanilla JS:

```
const URL = "http://127.0.0.1:5984"

function createDB(dbName) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("PUT", URL + "/" + dbName, true);
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    req.send();
}

function updateDB(dbName, docName, data) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("PUT", URL + '/' + dbName + '/' + docName, true);
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    req.send(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

So you'd use them like this:

```
createDB('baseball');
updateDB('baseball', 'document', {"pitcher":"Nolan Ryan"});
```

Note: I'm not going to get into revision numbers and conflict resolution here, just supplying some really basic code.  The second time you try to update the same record, there will be a conflict unless you supply the correct revision number, FYI.

```
updateDB('baseball', 'document', {"_rev":"1-7e007b1ef348cba88396435479822386", "pitcher":"Roger Clemens"});
```

Answer (score 3):

Checkout `jquery.couch.js`: https://github.com/daleharvey/jquery.couch.js-docs

Documentation is here: http://daleharvey.github.com/jquery.couch.js-docs/symbols/

Comment: To me this seems as good as the couch.js _wrapper_ (whatever that means) that's included with the couch itself. Not only the problem with pointing to my db persists, but this also presents a new problem of getting from seeing some files and folders @ github to using the documented methods in my script. All this couch-related stuff seems unfriendly to beginners :/

Comment: Checkout the test suite that comes with Futon (click test name to view the source): http://localhost:5984/_utils/couch_tests.html?script/couch_tests.js